# Laravel 5.2 Displaying Validation Error

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to validate a simple form by using Laravel's validator. Looks like validation works fine but i am unable to display errors. Form and controller looks like this.

Form

```
<h3>Add a New Team</h3>

<form method="POST" action="/teams">

    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="team_name" value="{{ old('team_name') }}" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn bg-primary">Add Team</button>
    </div>    
</form>

@if(count($errors))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Controller Method

```
public function store(Request $request) {

    $this->validate($request, [

        'team_name' => 'required|min:10'

    ]);

    $team = new Team;
    $team->team_name = $request->team_name;
    $team->save();

    return back();
}
```

If i remove web middleware group from my routes, errors displays fine.

Currently my `routes.php` file looks like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get('/teams', 'TeamsController@create');
    Route::post('/teams', 'TeamsController@store');

});
```

How do i fix this problem ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

why do use the validation looks like laravel 4 while you are using laravel 5!!

in laravel 5 you need first to make Request class that handle your validation

```
php artisan make:request RequestName
```

you will find the request class that you make in

> 'app/http/Requests/RequestName.php'

and in the rules function you can handle your validation

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // put  your validation rules here
            'team_name' => 'required|min:10'
        ];
    }
```

finally in your controller

```
use App\Http\Requests\RequestName;

public function store(RequestName $request) {
    Team::create($request->all());
    return Redirect::back();
}
```

for more illustration [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use Laravel [Form Request](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#form-request-validation)
run

```
artisan make:request TeamRequest
```

add some logic and rules

```
class TeamRequest extends Request {

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true; //you can put here any other variable or condition
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // put  your validation rules here
        ];
    }

}
```

then your contorller code will be like so:

```
public function store(TeamRequest $request)
{

    $team = Team::create($request->all());

    return back();
}
```

you no longer need to validate request and redirect back with errors and other stuff, laravel will do it for you
And you code looks more clean and neat, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Write below code in your controller :

```
// define rules
  $rules = array(
    'team_name' => 'required|min:10'
   );

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

if ($validator->fails())
{
  // something
   return Redirect::back()
          ->withErrors($validator) // send back all errors to the login form
          ->withInput();
}
else
{
  // something
   // save your data 
   $team = new Team;
   $team->team_name = $request->team_name;
   $team->save();
}
```

change in **View** File :

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Tried, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit research, i have found that Laravel 5.2 has a `RouteServiceProvider` and it includes web middleware group for all routes. So i do not have to add the web middleware group to my routes manually. I just removed it from `routes.php` and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

> If i remove web middleware group from my routes, errors displays fine.

In Laravel 5.2 the `web` midddleware is automatically applied to your routes in `routes.php` so no need to apply `web` middleware again. It is defined in `mapWebRoutes()` method of `RouteServiceProvider`.